# Difference between anonymous function vs named function as value for an object key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I have compiled JSX to JavaScript using Babel compiler. Here is the piece of code I'm intrigued with.

```
getInitialState: function getInitialState() {
//List out different states that ListComponent could possibly have
return {
  showList: true,
  listType: this.props.type
```

After compiling JSX to JS, getInitialState is a named method getInitialState(). I couldn't figure out why it isn't a anonymous method.

Original code:

```
getInitialState: function() {
//List out different states that ListComponent could possibly have
return {
  showList: true,
  listType: this.props.type
```

Is there any performance advantage writing like this?

Comment: In the past this made debugging easier. Now debuggers are intelligent enough to infer a name, see http://astithas.com/talks/qconsf2013/#/18/2

Comment: @Oriol it's still better than seeing functions called anonymous in the entire stack trace. :P

Comment: @Oriol it's (somewhat) important for recursive functions, or functions that otherwise need an internally-bound identifier to refer to themselves.

Comment: @Pointy I was assuming the code inside the function didn't reference the name. But yes, names function expressions replace the deprecated `arguments.callee`.

Comment: So you're showing the compiled code? What's the original source?

Comment: @Oriol In ES6 environments, ES6 actually ensures that many more cases of functions actually get a real name, not just an guessed name in the stack trace, so debuggers don't have to think about it. For example: ["If hasNameProperty is false, perform SetFunctionName(value, bindingId)."](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-let-and-const-declarations-runtime-semantics-evaluation) along with most of the other places `SetFunctionName` comes up in the spec.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no performance hit, except maybe the load time because of the file size.

Naming otherwise anonymous functions helps fixing issues since those names appear in the error stack traces in most browsers.

[This](https://vimeo.com/128582253) video does a good job at explaining what happens when you set names to anonymous functions.

Also this behavious has been included in the ECMA262 ES6 language specification. You can check that [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-let-and-const-declarations-runtime-semantics-evaluation).

Comment: Thanks a ton @toskv. That really helped me understand stuff.

Comment: Here's a link to video of Ben Nadel talking about this. Thanks @Oriol
https://vimeo.com/128582253

Comment: @AnveshChecka that's a very explanation of why you should name functions. Would you mind if I included that in the answer? :)

Comment: For those curious, while devtools have been doing this for a while now, this behavior is also now part of the ES6 spec: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-let-and-const-declarations-runtime-semantics-evaluation Note step #6: "If hasNameProperty is false, perform SetFunctionName(value, bindingId)."

Comment: @toskv Please go ahead

Answer (score 7):

The ES6 spec defines many places where the name of an anonymous function is explicitly set, based on the context of the function, even if no function name has been explicitly defined. Here are a bunch of examples.

[12.2.6.9](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer-runtime-semantics-propertydefinitionevaluation):

```
var o = {foo: function(){}};
o.foo.name === 'foo';
```

[12.14.4](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation):

```
var foo;
foo = function(){};
foo.name === 'foo';
```

[12.14.5.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-destructuringassignmentevaluation):

```
var {foo = function(){}} = {};
foo.name === 'foo';

var [foo = function(){}] = [];
foo.name === 'foo';
```

[12.14.5.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-iteratordestructuringassignmentevaluation):

```
var foo;
([foo = function(){}] = []);
foo.name === 'foo'
```

[12.15.5.4](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-keyeddestructuringassignmentevaluation):

```
var foo;
({foo = function(){}} = {});
foo.name === 'foo'
```

[13.3.1.4](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-let-and-const-declarations-runtime-semantics-evaluation):

```
let foo = function(){};
foo.name === 'foo'
```

[13.3.2.4](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-variable-statement-runtime-semantics-evaluation):

```
var foo = function(){};
foo.name === 'foo'
```

[13.3.3.6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-destructuring-binding-patterns-runtime-semantics-iteratorbindinginitialization):

```
function fn([foo = function(){}]){
    foo.name === 'foo';
}
fn([]);

function fn2({foo = function(){}}){
    foo.name === 'foo';
}
fn2({});
```

[14.1.19](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-instantiatefunctionobject):

```
export default function(){};

import foo from './self'; // Made-up circular ref.
foo.name === 'default';
```

[14.3.9](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-method-definitions-runtime-semantics-propertydefinitionevaluation):

```
var o = {foo(){}};
o.foo.name === 'foo';
class cls {foo(){}};
cls.prototype.foo.name === 'foo';
```